# Learning old html tags

Tags: html, css, search, xhtml

Do tags like `<em>,<strong>,<i>` or css properties like `font-size,text-decoration,font-weight` have any impact on the way search engines see my site?

Comment: Go ahead... learn about `<blink>`. Then learn what it's like to be reviled and hated by the entire web...

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer but the site won't let me: "*Well, the <a href="http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/">address</a> and <a href="http://html5doctor.com/the-abbr-element/">abbr</a> tags are not "old" in any meaningful sense, since they are still in HTML5 and have not been deprecated. `<dt>` is used in description lists, which are also still current. `<blink>` has few valid uses and you can safely ignore it, I think.*

Comment: "*In general you probably don't need an encyclopedic knowledge of the tags that are available to you, but some awareness of the existence of more exotic tags is probably good to have.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build sites from scratch, focus on the newest HTML version.  If you want to look at older sites, yes, it's a good idea to learn older HTML tags.  There are a lot of older HTML pages that are still up and running.